# How to Concat similar node values in XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a Source XML like below.

```
<Root>
    <E1 SEGMENT="1">
            <Node1>SomeValue</Node1>
            <Node2>I</Node2>
            <Node3>IT</Node3>
            <E2 SEGMENT="1">
                <TLINE>Val1</TLINE>
                <TF>*</TF>
            </E2>
            <E2 SEGMENT="1">
                <TLINE>Val2</TLINE>
                <TF>*</TF>
            </E2>
            <E2 SEGMENT="1">
                <TLINE>Val3</TLINE>
                <TF>*</TF>
            </E2>
            .....
            .....
            ......
            
        </E1>
</Root>
```

Expecting Output as below. source might be having more than 3 occurrences of E2 segment.

want to combine TLINE Values with a delimiter using XSLT.

```
<Root>
    <E1 SEGMENT="1">
            <Node1>SomeValue</Node1>
            <Node2>I</Node2>
            <Node3>IT</Node3>
            <E2 SEGMENT="1">
                <TLINE>Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |...</TLINE>
                <TF>*;*;*</TF>
            </E2>
    </E1>
</Root>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a trivial problem, esp. in XSLT 2.0. Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Perhaps the difficulty is because there are complications you haven't shown us, for example elements other than E2 or segment numbers other than 1? If so, you need to show us a less trivial example.

Comment: in E2 segment will always have "1" as the attribute , no other number, and these E2 only comes in E1.. and Ater E1 segment there will be other segments like node 5, node 6 etc.